# Show Woocommerce taxonomy in emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set up an attribute for my products "Delivery Time". I need to display this on the single product page, in the cart&checkout table an in the order emails.

I have been sucessfull in displaying in on the single product page and in the cart/order tables with this:

```
function wp_woo_cart_attributes( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

$item_data = $cart_item_key['data'];
$attributes = $item_data->get_attributes();


if ( ! $attributes ) {
    return $cart_item;
}

$out = $cart_item . '<br />';

foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {

    // skip variations
    if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
        continue;
    }
    $name = $attribute->get_name();
    if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {

        $product_id = $item_data->get_id();
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $name, 'all' );

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

                // get the taxonomy
                $tax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;

                // get the tax object
                $tax_object = get_taxonomy($tax);

                // get tax label
                if ( isset ( $tax_object->labels->singular_name ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->labels->singular_name;
                } elseif ( isset( $tax_object->label ) ) {
                    $tax_label = $tax_object->label;
                    // Trim label prefix since WC 3.0
                    $label_prefix = 'Product ';
                    if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label,  $label_prefix ) ) {
                        $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, strlen( $label_prefix ) );
                    }
                }
                $out .= $tax_label . ': ';
                $tax_terms = array();
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                    array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
                }
                $out .= implode(', ', $tax_terms). '<br />';

            }
        }

    } else {

        // not a taxonomy 

        $out .= $name . ': ';
        $out .= esc_html( implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() ) ) . '<br />';
    }
}
echo $out;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'wp_woo_cart_attributes', 10, 2 );

//Single Product
function product_attribute_delivery(){
global $product;

$taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
$value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

if ( $value ) {
    $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
    echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
}}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_dimensions', 25 );
```

How do I add it to the order emails, and is there even a solution for only displaying it on the single product page when the item is in stock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well let's make first the above code more simplified and keep it clean.

**You can delete this one if you want only to display the attribute in Single product page only**

```
//for Cart items and mini cart
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'wp_woo_cart_attributes', 10, 2);
function wp_woo_cart_attributes($cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{

    $productId = $cart_item_key['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($productId);
    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
    if ($value) {
        $label = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;
        $cart_item .= "<br><p> $label : $value</p>";
    }
    return $cart_item;
}
```

**Single Product**

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_delivery', 25);
function product_attribute_delivery()
{
    global $product;
    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);

    if ($value) {
        $label = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;
        echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
    }}
```

**to display specific taxonomy in Email Order Items**

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'custom_item_meta', 10, 4);

function custom_item_meta($item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text)
{

    $productId = $item->get_product_id();
    $product = wc_get_product($productId);
    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
    if ($value) {
        $label = get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name;
        echo  "<br><p> $label : $value</p>";
    }

}
```

the code above is tested and working correctly

Comment: Awesome, this is working EXACTLY how I want it to. I learned a lot!

Comment: That's Great news :)

Comment: If I also need to display the product thumbnail in the checkout table, your function is not working any longer. Any thoughts?

Comment: the functions above has nothing to do with thumbnail woocommerce by default doesn't display the product thumbnail in the checkout

Comment: no I know, but I NEED to also display the thumbnail and the function I am using for it

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', add_thumbnail_to_cart_items, 10, 3 );
    function add_thumbnail_to_cart_items( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){ 
        // Only on checkout page
        if ( ! is_checkout() ) return $product_name;
    
        $product     = $cart_item['data']; 
        $thumbnail   = $product->get_image(array( 60, 60)); 
    
        $opening_div = '<div id="checkout_thumbnail" style="float:left; padding-right:10px;">'; 
        return $opening_div . $thumbnail . '</div> ' . $product->get_name(); 
    }

Comment: if I also add this, the attribute is not being displayed any longer.

Comment: mark am just a bit confused here in the comments so if you please ask another question and i will be happy to check your code and help you

Comment: of course, I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009122/displaying-product-photo-in-order-table