# WooCommerce: Get image thumbnail in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the product image in Woocommerce checkout page.
After some research I found *[Displaying product thumbnail and attribute in Woocommerce cart and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009122/displaying-product-thumbnail-and-attribute-in-woocommerce-cart-and-checkout/52009356#52009356)* answer code. It works fine., but the images are too heavy. They have the witdh/height of 70px but the original image is way bigger.

Is there an option to use the WooCommerce thumbnail size `gallery_thumbnail_image_width`?

I tried to use the thumbnail size with `get_image()` like they write in the docs (https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_image/):

```
$thumbnail   = $cart_item['data']->get_image('gallery_thumbnail_image_width');
```

But that doesn't work. It's still the bigger image.

Is there anythin I miss?

Comment: The smaller size for default WooCommerce images size is "woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail" which is 100 x 100 px … So if you are using a size array like `array(70,70);` it will use CSS to get the image smaller based on an image size of 100 x 100 px. You can also define your own image custom sizes, but this require to process all existing images in the media library…

Comment: yes, I saw that there is an extra class for that. But in my case the base image is the full size image of the product. So the browser has to load the big image, right? But the 100 x 100 px version would be more than enough.

Comment: No wrong… It loads the 100px x 100px (But all sizes urls are embedded)… have a look to the generated source code…

Comment: I have. I guess I have a problem with my theme then

Comment: Maybe yes… because the source is normally `src="…100x100.jpg"` and all other sizes are embedded in the `srcset` property.

Comment: OK, strange. The rest of the images are that way. But thanks to point me in the right direction